# How to get difference between two consecutive rows for a column field using group by and order by

Tags: sql

EmpNo   Dept    Sales
1   10  9
2   20  7
1   10  10
1   10  5
3   10  3
3   10  8
1   10  11
4   30  5
4   30  5

EmpNo   Dept    Sales   Growth
1   10  5   5
1   10  9   4
1   10  10  1
1   10  11  1
3   10  3   3
3   10  8   5
2   20  7   7
4   30  5   5
4   30  6   1

Comment: You need to be able to order the data, there's no such column in your example. Then it's based on LAG: `sales - lag(sales, 1, 0) over (partition by EmpNo order by ???)`

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAG` to get the last value partitioned by employee, but you need an additional column (like an id or date) to order the columns. This is a simple example with just the first few records of your example (adding an `id` column):

```
SELECT *,
    Sales - LAG(Sales, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpNo ORDER BY Id) AS Growth
FROM SalesData
```

With sample data

```
;WITH SalesData (Id, EmpNo, Dept, Sales) AS (
    SELECT 1, 1, 10, 9
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1,10, 10
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 2, 10, 7
)
    SELECT *,
        Sales - LAG(Sales, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpNo ORDER BY Id) AS Growth
    FROM SalesData
```

This example produces:

```
Id          EmpNo       Dept        Sales       Growth
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           10          9           9
2           1           10          10          1
3           2           10          7           7
```

Comment: Thanks your response was very helpful.  Which function can we use to take the difference of the sale's data from each row - sale's data of the initial row?